# What's the best way to work around function name conflicts in R?

Tags: r

In loading a few packages to work with some data, I received an error when I tried to use the function `select()` from the `dplyr` package.  I was trying to use a new package (to me), `MASS`, so I was easily able to diagnose and get things working properly.  This experience made me curious, though, about the optimal way to work in a world of many packages, with functions that conflict with one another.

Consider the following code and error message:

```
library(dplyr)
library(MASS)


df<-data.frame(Lobsters=c(1,3,4,5,7,1),Llamas=c(7,1,2,5,8,3))

df2<-df%>%
  select(Lobsters)
```

> Error in select(.,Lobsters) : unused argument (Lobsters)

While this error makes it clear that select() is giving me the problem, it doesn't necessarily make it clear to me that the problem is that I'm not calling on the `select()` function I'm used to.

I know I can call the `dplyr` function and get my desired result using:

```
df2_alt<-df%>%
  dplyr::select(Lobsters)
```

I wonder, though:

1. Is there a best practice in diagnosing problems with same-named functions, besides the "The following object is masked from" messages when a package is loaded?
2. Is my method of `dplyr::select(` the best way to work around these conflicts?

Ultimately, my current strategy is to load the package that has the `select()` function I'll be using more after the package that has the less-frequently-used version.

Comment: Check out the [conflicted](https://conflicted.r-lib.org/) package.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some things that can be done.

1. When issuing a `library` statement, R will list all conflicts.  Pay attention to these! If you need to know the conflicts later enter: `conflicts()` .
2. Use the `exclude` argument on `library` (R 3.6 and later). e.g. `library(MASS, exclude = "select")`.  dplyr clobbers base `lag` and `filter` so you might want to get into the habit of routinely excluding those: `library(dplyr, exclude = c("filter", "lag"))`  One can still access them using `dplyr::lag`, etc.
3. Use `dplyr::select` notation if you find it has been masked.
4. `detach` any packages you are no longer using, e.g. `detach("package:MASS")` .
5. In some cases the masking is benign since the new version it is backwardly compatible and in those cases there is no need to avoid the conflict.
6. As noted by @LenGreski in the comments the package order will determine the resolution of any conflicts. Each package overrides all prior packages that were loaded before it in the case of conflicts.

There are also a number of packages that address the problem of conflicts including [conflicted](https://cran.r-project.org/package=conflicted) (mentioned by @MrFlick), [modules](https://cran.r-project.org/package=modules), [import](https://cran.r-project.org/package=import) and [box](https://cran.r-project.org/package=box) which are all on CRAN.

Comment: One item to consider adding to your list is the package load order. If one doesn't need `MASS::select()`, one can load `MASS` before `dplyr` and subsequently use the `dplyr` version of `select()`.

Answer (score 4):

Using `dplyr::select` avoids ambiguity. In my opinion, that's the best you can do.

The drawback of not calling `library(dplyr)` is that the `pipe` is not in available. You can still do `library(magrittr)` to get it available. Or you can have a look at the nice `import` package that is very useful if you don't want to attach packages. Basically, if you do `import::from("magrittr", "%>%")`, you can use the pipe without attaching any package.